# How linux's user space allocates memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel

Maybe it is very silly question. However I can not find a proper answer in google until now.

We can find so many document and website which explain how linux kernel allocates some memory, like slab / buddy / kmalloc / vmalloc...
My question is how linux's user application allocates memory which they want.
Can it be done without kernel's help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooner or later the user-space allocator is going to need pages of memory mapped into the virtual address space of the process, and that can only be done by the kernel.

So the answer to your last question is no, it can not be done without the kernels help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, another and same question, which API in Linux return a virtual address for user space ?

Comment: @LJinho Usually one uses the [`sbrk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) function.